# Swappiness for aggressive swapping

Tags: swap, memory-usage

I want to configure the Ubuntu 14.04 with aggressive swapping behavior. I'm using Linux kernel 3.14. I modified the swappiness using the following command.

```
echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

However, the OS doesn't seem to swap out pages until the host runs out of free memory. How can I make the OS to proactively swap out the un-accessed pages to the swap device?

Answer (score 3):

Use the ram for something else.  Processes allocating memory or disk IO trying to allocate cache will push out idle pages to swap to make room.  The swappiness variable just makes the system prefer to push applications out to favor using ram for the filesystem cache instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ever want to do that for?

Anyway, if that's what you want, that's what you'll get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

fGetMyRAM()
{
    FILE* fStream = popen( "head -n1 /proc/meminfo", "r" );
    std::ostringstream output;
    int iBuffer = 128;

    while( !feof( fStream ) && !ferror( fStream ))
    {
        char cBuffer[iBuffer];
        int iBytesRead = fread( cBuffer, 1, iBuffer, fStream );
        output.write( cBuffer, iBytesRead );
    }
    std::string sResult = output.str();

    std::string sLabel, sRAM;
    std::istringstream iss(sResult);
    iss >> sLabel;
    iss >> sRAM;

    return std::stoi( sRAM );
}

int main()
{
  int iMyRAM = fGetMyRAM();
  int *pMemoryHog;

  while (true)
  {
    //as malloc alocates largest contiguous memory, keep slicing down.
    iMyRam = iMyRam/2;

    printf("%d\n", iMyRam);

    pMemoryHog = (int *) malloc ((iMyRam)*sizeof(void *));

    if (pMemoryHog == 0)
    {
      printf("Yeah! NO MORE MEMORY!\n");
      return 1;
    } // end if out of memory
    strcpy(pMemoryHog, "42");
  } // end while true
  free(pMemoryHog);
  return 0;
} // end main
```

Comment: That won't quite work: you can allocate *tons* of virtual memory with malloc, but the physical pages won't really be allocated until you touch that memory.  Also I'm not sure why you are going into an infinite loop to waste cpu time.

Comment: You could add a few more lines of code to go and touch the first byte of each page allocated and ditch the infinite loop and the program would have the desired effect.

Comment: Yeah, but my point was: *Why would you want to do that* and the source code was intended to point that out, not to *actually* eat up all his memory, but if you think it'll help, I'll leave it as is now.  I'm off to bed, so if you still find an error, feel free to edit...